# Find nearest neighbors using KDTree between two datasets

Tags: python, scipy, kdtree

I want to find nearest neighbors between two datasets: `data_1` and `data_2`. KDTree calculates nearest neighbors including the neighbors in its own dataset.

For example, `data_1[i] and data_1[i+1]` might be the closest points overall, but I need points `data_1[i] and data_2[j]` which are closest between those datasets. So, in essence, I need one neighbor to be from `data_1` and the other from `data_2`.

So instead of global (combined) nearest neighbors I specifically want closest neighbor from other dataset.

Comment: My suggestion might not make sense because I'm not familiar with this sort of thing.. but can you combine the data sets in the same tree, but somehow mark each datapoint as being from set 1 vs set 2. So that way you use the nearest neighbor approach, then from the returned set, filter out the points from whichever data set you're looking for?

Comment: or maybe you don't have to modify the representation of the data at all. Just combine the data into one set.. then find the nearest neighbors.. get that set.. then for each item in that set use `if pt[n] in set_2: ` etc.

Comment: @Todd, thanks for the suggestion. But I can think of at least one reason that might not work. The goal of KDTree is to find the nearest neighbors. If I combine the datasets (and mark each datapoint somehow ), KDTree still gives the nearest neighbor from the same dataset.  Or I will have to measure distances of all points in the combined dataset to all other datapoints, which is same as what ```scipy.cdist``` does. It's prohibitively expensive for my datasets.

Comment: It's not possible to combine all the data points together into one kd tree?

Comment: It is possible. But the problem arises when I query for nearest neighbors. If I set ```k=2```, it gives the two nearest points in the combined dataset (which probably are from the same dataset). For me to get distances from all points in the combined to all other points, I will have to set ```k=len(data_1)+len(data_2)``` which is too expensive. 
Also, if I might use an analogy, let's say we have a bunch of cities in Germany and France. I want to find a French city that is nearest to a German city. While all KDTree does is give two nearest French cities.

Comment: If this were for something like collision detection between 3d models.. I suppose that combining spatial points into one tree you could query for closest points and if none are from the other dataset you're fine.. but if points from the other data set (a wall) show up, then you've run into it?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is just interesting to me and I see the scipy docs here.. is this applicable? scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_tree

Comment: ```scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_tree``` might actually work. Thanks. Let me check and get back to you.